# Stata multinomial regression - post-estimation Wald test

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, multinomial

I've conducted a multinomial logistic regression analysis in Stata, followed by a Wald test, and was hoping someone could confirm that my code is doing what I think it's doing.

NB: I'm using some of Stata's example data to illustrate. The analysis I'm running for this illustration is completely meaningless, but uses the same procedure as my 'real' analysis, other than the fact that my real analysis also includes some probability weights and other covariates.

```
sysuse auto.dta
```

First, I run a multinomial logistic regression, predicting 'Repair Record' from 'Foreign' and 'Price':

```
mlogit rep78 i.foreign price, base(1) rrr nolog

Multinomial logistic regression                 Number of obs     =         69
                                                LR chi2(8)        =      31.15
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0001
Log likelihood = -78.116372                     Pseudo R2         =     0.1662

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |        RRR   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1            |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
2            |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |   .7822853   1672.371    -0.00   1.000            0           .
       price |   1.000414   .0007027     0.59   0.556     .9990375    1.001792
       _cons |   .5000195   1.669979    -0.21   0.836      .000718    348.2204
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
3            |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |     686842   1.30e+09     0.01   0.994            0           .
       price |   1.000462   .0006955     0.66   0.507     .9990996    1.001826
       _cons |   1.254303   4.106511     0.07   0.945     .0020494    767.6863
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
4            |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |    6177800   1.17e+10     0.01   0.993            0           .
       price |   1.000421   .0006999     0.60   0.547     .9990504    1.001794
       _cons |   .5379627     1.7848    -0.19   0.852     .0008067    358.7452
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
5            |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |   2.79e+07   5.29e+10     0.01   0.993            0           .
       price |   1.000386   .0007125     0.54   0.587     .9989911    1.001784
       _cons |    .146745   .5072292    -0.56   0.579     .0001676    128.4611
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Second, I want to know whether the 'Foreign' coefficient for outcome category 4 is significantly different to the 'Foreign' coefficient for outcome category 5. So, I run a Wald test:

```
test [4]1.foreign = [5]1.foreign

 ( 1)  [4]1.foreign - [5]1.foreign = 0

           chi2(  1) =    2.72
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0988
```

From this, I conclude that the 'Foreign' coefficient for outcome category 4 is NOT significantly different to the 'Foreign' coefficient for outcome category 5. Put more simply, the association between 'Foreign' and 'Repair 4' (compared to 'Repair 1') is equal to the association between 'Foreign' and 'Repair 5'  (compared to 'Repair 1') .

Is my code for the Wald test, and my inferences about what it's doing and showing, correct?

Comment: The Wald test concludes that, based on an arbritary alpha of 0.05, that there is no evidence of a difference between the two effects. However, a lack of evidence for a difference between the effects is not equivalent to evidence that the effects are the same. Check out `Greenland et al. (2016) Statistical tests, P values, confidence intervals, and power: a guide to misinterpretations` for a good overview.

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree I was somewhat lax in how I expressed my interpretations in relation to null hypothesis testing. But is the code correct?

Comment: Yes, the code is indeed correct to perform the Wald test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally, to what was discussed in the comments you can also perform a likelihood-ratio test using the following code.

```
sysuse auto.dta

qui mlogit rep78 i.foreign price, base(1) rrr nolog 
estimate store unrestricted

constraint 1 [4]1.foreign = [5]1.foreign

qui mlogit rep78 i.foreign price, base(1) rrr nolog constraints(1)
estimate store restricted

lrtest unrestricted restricted
```

The output of the test shows the same conclusion as the Wald test, but it has better properties as explained below.

```
Likelihood-ratio test                                 LR chi2(1)  =      3.13
(Assumption: restricted nested in unrestricted)       Prob > chi2 =    0.0771
```

Quoting the official [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmlogit.pdf) from `mlogit`

> The results produced by `test` are an approximation based on the estimated covariance matrix of the coefficients. Because the probability of being uninsured is low, the log-likelihood may be nonlinear for the uninsured. Conventional statistical wisdom is not to trust the asymptotic answer under these circumstances but to perform a likelihood-ratio test instead.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!  My analysis includes some probability weights, and when I tried this, Stata produced the following error: `LR test likely invalid for models with robust vce`. Do you have any further suggestions? If the Wald test isn't completely 'trustworthy', as it were, does that mean I can't do either?

Comment: This is an interesting issue that comes around every now and then. Indeed, it is so frequently asked that _StataCorp_ provided an official explanation that you can find [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/likelihood-ratio-test/). In short, what happens is that when clustering or using weights observations are no longer independent, therefore it is not a true likelihood. In such cases _Wald tests_ should be preferred. Does it solve your question @Alice?